# wp.getPosts with status = 'trash' using node.js

Tags: filters, trash, post-status

I was wondering how to set the filter option for wp.getPosts. I want to get posts with a status of 'trash'. filter is currently blank, and returns all posts other than trash.

I am using the xmlrpc wordpress api and the node-wordpress plugin. https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-wordpress

Here is my current code:

```
wp.getPosts('<filter>', ['title','status'], function(err, data){

});
```

I am not sure what to put in the filter section, all the examples I could find are PHP examples and do not work in this context where I am using Javascript.

Is it even possible to get the posts with a status of 'trash'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this...

```
wp.getPosts({
      status: 'trash',
    },
    ['title','status'],
    function( err, data ) {
      console.log( data );
    }
});
```